# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cache_info' with functools.lru_cache + argument formatting decorator discrepancy

Tags: python, caching, decorator, attributeerror, functools

I made up this simple, contrived example of some code I ran into at work. I'm trying to better understand why slow_function_1 (+ the way its decorators are structured) would cache function results properly, but the decorator applied to slow_function_2 would not. In this example, I'm trying to access cache information after calling the method; however, I consistently get the following error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'cache_info'`. I've searched high and low to try to fix this, but to no avail. This AttributeError is raised for both `slow_function_1.cache_info()` and `slow_function_2.cache_info()`

How do I view the cache between function calls? If anyone has any insight on the original problem of why slow_function_1 and slow_function_2 differ in caching behavior, I would appreciate that as well.

Thank you in advance!

```
import functools
import time

def format_args(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        formatted_args = [tuple(x) if type(x) == list else x for x in args]
        return func(*formatted_args, **kwargs)
    return inner

def formatted_cache(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        formatted_args = [tuple(x) if type(x) == list else x for x in args]
        return functools.lru_cache()(func)(*formatted_args, **kwargs)
    return inner

@format_args
@functools.lru_cache
def slow_function_1(a: list, b: bool):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("executing slow function 1")
    return sum(a)


@formatted_cache
def slow_function_2(a: list, b: bool):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("executing slow function 2")
    return functools.reduce((lambda x, y: x*y), a)


example_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
example_bool = True

slow_function_1(example_list, example_bool)
print(slow_function_1.cache_info())
slow_function_1(example_list, example_bool)
print(slow_function_1.cache_info())


slow_function_2(example_list, example_bool)
print(slow_function_2.cache_info())
slow_function_2(example_list, example_bool)
print(slow_function_2.cache_info())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I stared at it for a good time, I don't think it's really possible to do this with a decorator. You need a `lru_cache` object to access the cache and all that stuff, and you need a second function to format the arguments to be hashable before passing to the `lru_cache` object. The decorator can't return both at once, and they can't be nested in each other to make one function with the best of both worlds.

```
def formatted_cache(func):
    # first we assume func only takes in hashable arguments
    # so cachedfunc only takes in hashable arguments
    cachedfunc = functools.lru_cache(func)
    
    # inner formats lists to hashable tuples
    # then passes it to cachedfunc
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        formatted_args = [tuple(x) if type(x) == list else x for x in args]
        return cachedfunc(*formatted_args, **kwargs)
    
    # oh no, we can only return one function, but neither is good enough
```

I think the only way to move forward is to just accept that these have to be done in separate functions because of `lru_cache`'s limitation. It's not that awkward, actually, just a simple higher order function like `map`.

```
import functools
import time

def formatted_call(func, *args, **kwargs):
    formatted_args = [tuple(x) if type(x) == list else x for x in args]
    return func(*formatted_args, **kwargs)

@functools.lru_cache
def slow_function_2(a: list, b: bool):
    time.sleep(1)
    print("executing slow function 2")
    return functools.reduce((lambda x, y: x*y), a)

example_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
example_bool = True

formatted_call(slow_function_2, example_list, example_bool)
print(slow_function_2.cache_info())
formatted_call(slow_function_2, example_list, example_bool)
print(slow_function_2.cache_info())
```

Comment: Hi BatWannaBe, thanks for your reply! I tried this code segment in place of the 8 lines at the bottom of the script, and it threw the error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'cache_info'`.

Comment: Now that I take a closer look, I think it's the way your decorators are wrapping `lru_cache`. You seem to want to make a the `slow_function`s into cacheing callables, but your outer decorators are not returning anything like that at all. I'll amend my post and give it a try